# Does every infinite $\Sigma^1_1$ set have an infinite $\Delta^1_1$ subset?

Tags: logic, computability, descriptive-set-theory

The question is exactly that in the title: Does every infinite $\Sigma^1_1$ set of natural numbers have an infinite $\Delta^1_1$ subset?

Some background: The lower-level analog of this question, Does every infinite c.e. set have an infinite computable subset?, is easily seen to be true. However, this is in some sense the *wrong* analog of the question I want to ask. The correct intuition in higher recursion theory tends to be that $\Delta^1_1$ corresponds to finite, as opposed to computable, and that the correct analog of "c.e." is $\Pi^1_1$ rather than $\Sigma^1_1$. This makes me guess that the answer to my question is "no," since the only reason I have for favoring "yes" is based on an incorrect analogy.

I also imagine that the answer (whether a counterexample or a proof) is fairly simple. This is why I have posted on MathSE as opposed to MathOF. I have looked at Sacks' book "Higher Recursion Theory" (which can be gotten freely at Project Euclid: [Link](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Higher-Recursion-Theory/toc/pl/1235422631)), but I have not been able to find the answer there.

This question has no broad significance; I am just interested in understanding the analytic hierarchy better, and this seemed like a problem I ought to understand.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Now when you say $\Sigma^1_1$ and $\Delta^1_1$ do you mean analytic and Borel (resp.)? Because *every* subset of a countable $T_1$ space is $F_\sigma$ (or $\Sigma^0_2$ in the Borel hierarchy).

Comment: I'm using the lightface hierarchy - so, for example, there are only countably many $\Delta^1_1$ sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there exists an infinite $\Sigma_1^1$ set which has no infinite $\Delta_1^1$ subset.

In the $\omega$ computability case, this can be proved by constructing a simple set. Recall a simple set is a c.e. set whose complement is immune. A set is immune if it contains no infinite c.e. set. Thus the complement of a simple set is a $\Pi_1^0$ set which has no infinite computable (in fact c.e.) subset. Therefore, the idea is that the analogous of c.e. subsets (of $\omega$) in $\omega_1^{CK}$ admissible computability or metacomputability are the $\Pi_1^1$ subsets. Therefore, one should just show that the simple set construction works in this new setting.

The details are the following: By Proposition V 1.2 in Sacks, $A \subset \omega$ is metarecursively enumerable if and only if it is $A$ is $\Pi_1^1$. By exercise VII 1.12 $A$ is metarecursively enumerable if and only if $A$ is $\omega_1^{CK}$ recursively enumerable. For any $\alpha$ a admissible ordinal (for example $\omega_1^{CK}$), there exist a enumeration theorem, i.e Sacks VII 1.9. Thus there is a enumeration of all $\omega_1^{CK}$ r.e. subsets of $\omega_1^{CK}$. Since $\omega < \omega_1^{CK}$, $\omega \in L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$. Thus one can easily make an enumeration of all $\omega_1^{CK}$-c.e. subsets of $\omega$, i.e. the $\Pi_1^1$ subsets.

Now define a set to be $\Pi_1^1$-immune if it is infinite and contains no infinite $\omega_1^{CK}$ ($\Pi_1^1$) subset. A set is $\Pi_1^1$-simple if it is $\omega_1^{CK}$-c.e. and has immune complement. With an enumeration of all the $\Pi_1^1$ subsets of $\omega$, I think you can carry over the regular proof to prove there exists a $\Pi_1^1$-simple set. Its complement is then the desired $\Sigma_1^1$ set with no infinite $\Delta_1^1$ subset.

I hope this works. If you know a more elementary proof, please post it.

Answer (score 3):

No.
The set $\{x\mid \omega_1=\omega_1^{CK} \wedge x \not\in HYP\}$ does not contain a non empty $\Delta^1_1$ subset. But the proof is not trivial.

Hjorth and Nies has another nice example. They constructed a $\Sigma^1_1$ closed set in which every real is $\Pi^1_1$-Martin-Löf random. Then the set does not contain any nonempty $\Delta^1_1$ subset.